# Hive - How to mention Null value check with one Numeric value on same column

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I am not getting expected result when mentioned Not Null check with one Numeric value on same column. It's returning all the values.

```
Select *
from TableName
where Col1 = value
and (col2 is Not Null or col2 <> 123)
```

Here, `col2` is Numeric column.
Expected Result = Exclude records where Col2 having Null value or 123
Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are getting all the rows, except the `NULL` ones.  One solution is to replace the `or` with `and`.  But that logic is actually redundant:

```
where Col1 = value and col2 <> 123
```

`NULL` fails the `<> 123` comparison, so you don't need another check.

Answer (score 0):

I get the correct result from below query. As per following requirement, I was using Or in place of And.

Select *
from TableName
where Col1 = value
and (col2 is Not Null and col2 <> 123)